# Need to Modify Header Text in an Excel File

Tags: excel, vb.net, oledb, adodb

UPDATE2: I opted to go the the EPPlus NuGet package which is very easy to use via simple/straightforward code. That said, if you still would prefer OLEDB/ADODB, I was stipulating the wrong version of Excel in the Extended Properties portion of the connection string (strConnect). Thanks to TnTinMn for the correction (see comments).

UPDATE: solution found to this issue but a new issue has arisen. See end of original post.

I'm using VB.Net in Visual Studio 2017. I have a need to be able to modify/change the header text in multiple Excel files. I have read LOTS of posts (here and elsewhere) and nothing I've found seems to work. I've tried OLEDB and ADODB. I cannot use Excel/Office project references because this code will run on an Utility Server that will never have MS Office installed on it (hence OLEDB/ADODB) and it will run under a Service Account which will not be able to interact with desktop apps (if Office was installed).

Here's what I've most recently tried (among other things) within a Try/Catch:

```
    ' Create the connection string
    strConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source=" & arrFilePath(i) & "; Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=No'"
    ' Create the SQL statement
    strSQL1 = "UPDATE [Sheet1$A1:A1] SET F1='Disbursement Status';"
    strSQL2 = "UPDATE [Sheet1$B1:B1] SET F2='Check/ACH Number';"

    ' Create and open the Connection object
    objConn = New ADODB.Connection
    objConn.Open(strConnect)

    ' Execute the insert statements
    objConn.Execute(strSQL1)
    objConn.Execute(strSQL2)

    ' Close the Connection object
    objConn.Close()
```

What's odd is that the first Update statement (strSQL1) will work. So, I figured I'd try the second (strSQL2). That results in the dread "No value given for one or more required parameters" error. I'm sure the solution is pretty simple but it's escaping me, for some reason (not for lack of research).

[This is an image of the data layout with which I'm working. I need to change the header text in cell B1 and cell M1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qibgn.png)

Any help/suggestions is greatly appreciated.

---

New problem:
These .xlsx files are created via export from SAP. When I try to manipulate them (by using the code above), the header text is not changed but no errors are thrown by the code. It seems the only way to actually make changes is to manually open them in Excel, make the header text changes and then Save them. Grrr. Maybe EP Plus is the solution after all. Thoughts?

---

Problems solved!

Comment: You could use a library like EPPlus. It will let you do the things that MS Office InterOp does, without needed Excel installed on the server.

Comment: Little guess here I admit, what if you where to change your sql update from 'Check/ACH Number' to 'Check ACH Number' dropping the slash?  Just wondering if that is doing some sort of unexpected escaping

Comment: In your second sql statement, change `F2` to `F1` as the range `Sheet1$B1:B1` is only one column wide and has no _field #2_.

Comment: @HardCode: EP Plus is a NuGet package? I've seen other posts that reference that but have never really looked into it.

Comment: @Hursey: I'm trying to match SQL Server table column names so I don't have to use the SQL Bulk Copy Column Mapping class. But, I will tinker with you idea. Thanks.

Comment: @TnTinMn: Your suggestion worked! Thanks very much.

Comment: A new issue has popped up, see OP. I may have to tinker with EP Plus after all. =/

Comment: 'New problem: These .xlsx files` - then why are you using "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0".  It should be "Excel 12.0 Xml". See:  [Xlsx files](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsx-files/).

Comment: @Bronco638 yes, EPPlus is a NuGet package.

Comment: @TnTinMn Because I'm stupid. SMH.

Comment: @HardCode Thanks, yes, I've installed it and it's super easy. So, I'm going with that approach. Thanks for all of the responses.